# Eventbridge - Use FIFO SQS for deduplication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-event-bridge, aws-sqs-fifo

I need some events to be delivered exactly once, but I have no control of the message processor (so I can‘t make the recipient idempotent).

Is it possible to route events from Eventbridge to a FIFO SQS for deduplication and from the FIFO sqs to the recipient (lambda on other account? Would this achieve exact-once delivery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It EventBridge (EB) has [at-least-once](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/features/) deliver which means you can get more then one event of the same type. But if this is not an issue, and your only concern is SQS, then yes, [EB supports SQS FIFO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-automating-using-eventbridge.html) targets:

> EventBridge lets you set a variety of targets—such as Amazon SQS standard and **FIFO queues**—which receive events in JSON format.

Comment: EB supports FIFO queues as a target, but I think the question was about FIFO queue deduplication?

Answer (score 1):

Can you set dynamically messageGroupId from the payload content when you set SQS FIFO as a target for your EventBridge rule?

From the current setup I see that it can be only a hardcoded value.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is not possible, I have just hit the same problem, if you have found a solution I'd love to know what it was?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you have to configure the FIFO queue. It can detect duplicates based on the body of the message. See this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues-exactly-once-processing.html).

> FIFO queues help you avoid sending duplicates to a queue. If you retry
> the SendMessage action within the 5-minute deduplication interval,
> Amazon SQS doesn't introduce any duplicates into the queue.

The link goes on to state what configurations are required, so be sure to check it out.